# Firefox JPM ignores homepage options

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk, jpm

I just switched to JPM from CFX and am stuck on this issue.

When I execute `jpm run -p myDevProfile`, it opens Firefox with the profile correctly, and all the bookmarks and addon settings are there.
However, in this profile, the homepage is set to `http://google.com` or `Restore tabs from last session`, but every time I restart the browser for a new build, JPM has set the homepage to `Show blank page` and `about:blank` is loaded.

How can I fix this? I've tried creating fresh profiles with nothing changed except the Homepage option and set JPM to use the new profiles, but it still resets on every launch. The same profile works as expected when using `cfx run -p myDevProfile` instead.